# Series of short stories in which the main character has Nemaline Myopathy, lives in orbit in his own space station

Tags: story-identification

Series of short stories.  Main character has Nemaline Myopathy, lives in orbit in his own space station.

Comment: So, what is the character's deal, other than having that disease? Is he an inventor? A philosopher? A terrorist? Religious messiah?

Comment: And when did you read this? What language? Hardback? Paperback? EBook? Website?

Comment: possiby the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/200130/story-about-a-paralysed-man-making-self-replicating-robot-arms

Answer (score 8):

Other than his disease being *myasthenia gravis* and there only being a single story, this could be Robert Heinlein's "[Waldo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waldo_(short_story))".

> Waldo Farthingwaite-Jones was born a weakling, unable even to lift his head up to drink or to hold a spoon. Far from destroying him, this channeled his intellect, and his family's money, into the development of the device patented as "Waldo F. Jones' Synchronous Reduplicating Pantograph". Wearing a glove and harness, Waldo could control a much more powerful mechanical hand simply by moving his hand and fingers. This and other technologies he develops make him a rich man, rich enough to build a home in space.

Comment: I feel a bit bad posting this when it really doesn't directly match the sparse details you've provided, but it matches the general meaning of what you've stated. This may, at least, help you determine more details about your story by how it doesn't match my answer.

Comment: Thank you!  This is not exactly what I remember, but it's so close I'll take this answer and assume my memory is faulty.  THANK YOU!

Comment: Ah, you can click on the checkmark to accept as per the [tour].

Comment: If accepted, possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/95820/28516 which is a story ID question that has Waldo as the accepted answer.

Comment: {nods} Very different question, but as per policy...